# How to create an oval UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

To make a circle view one must do

```
shapeView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(width)/2.0
```

So I extended this logic to make an oval view

```
if width >= height {
    shapeView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(width)/2.0
} else{
    shapeView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(height)/2.0
}
```

Except my oval views have pointy ends as you can see [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdvq8.png)

My question is: How do I get rid of the pointy ends and make them round?

---

If it's any concern I'm using:

- Swift 2
- IOS 9.2
- Xcode 7.2

Comment: You can't create an oval using `cornerRadius`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a `CAShapeLayer` as your layer mask:

```
class OvalView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layoutOvalMask()
    }

    private func layoutOvalMask() {
        let mask = self.shapeMaskLayer()
        let bounds = self.bounds
        if mask.frame != bounds {
            mask.frame = bounds
            mask.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(bounds, nil)
        }
    }

    private func shapeMaskLayer() -> CAShapeLayer {
        if let layer = self.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer {
            return layer
        }
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.layer.mask = layer
        return layer
    }

}
```

Demo:

```
let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 250))
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
let ovalView = OvalView(frame: CGRectMake(25, 25, 400, 200))
backgroundView.addSubview(ovalView)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.jpg"))
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
imageView.frame = ovalView.bounds
ovalView.addSubview(imageView)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = backgroundView
```

Result:

[image: oval mask]

Comment: For Swift 3, the follow changed: `mask.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: bounds, transform: nil)` and `layer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor`

Answer (score 0):

```
float w = 150.0f;
float h = 50.0f;
self.MyView.frame = CGRectMake(95, 461, w, w);
self.MyView.layer.cornerRadius = w / 2;
```

[image]